# Can I have the I-beam (mouse) cursor more visible in gtk3 apps?

Tags: mouse, gtk3, cursor

When the mouse cursor hovers over text (other than hypertext?) that can be edited or copied , the cursor appears as an I-Beam insertion bar.

In `gtk2`, it's possible to alter the width and color of the I-beam by merely editing a couple of lines in my theme's `gtkrc` file like this:

```
GtkWidget::cursor-color = "red"  
GtkWidget::cursor_aspect_ratio = 0.2
```

Is there something similar available for `gtk3` themes? (Apparently such a feature isn't yet available in [qt apps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68715/15760).)

I'm using Lubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file to be edited is `gtk-widgets.css` in `usr/share/themes/theme_name/gtk-3.0` or in `~/.themes/theme_name/gtk-3.0`. To adjust the width, the code to be inserted is this:

```
 -GtkWidget-cursor-aspect-ratio: 0.3;
```

or other suitable value.