# Keyboard Cursor Invisible during Rename in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, cursor, rename

When I rename a directory, the background color is white, text color is black, but the blinking Keyboard cursor color is also white or it is invisible !! So I am not able to position the cursor for renaming.
I am using a custom theme "Ambience Dark" (11.04's Default).
How can I change the cursor color so that it is in contrast with the rename background ?

Comment: Are you using some custom theme?

Comment: Yes, Ambience Dark(11.04 Default Theme). But even if I switch back to original theme in 12.04, there is no change. Still the rename cursor is invisible. I have to type to know where the cursor is !!

Comment: Also, see if this helps you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/284848/can-i-have-the-i-beam-mouse-cursor-more-visible-in-gtk3-apps You can choose a color for the "I-beam" cursor.

Comment: Solved, but it was some kind of magic !! I just changed the aspect ratio to 0.5 and it worked. But thereafter cursor is visible even if I delete the aspect ratio or change it to any value !!!

Comment: @vasa1 Now the cursor is visible. How to change the color of the I-beam. Edit gtk-2.0's gtkrc file ??

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I had to add a line to this css file `~/.themes/theme_name/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css`

```
-GtkWidget-cursor-aspect-ratio: 0.3
```

But thereafter, the cursor stays visible even if I remove the above line !!