# Text cursor color should change according to language

Tags: unity, indicator, language-support

OK, there is a language indicator/selector at top of Unity (I am on Ubuntu 12.04).

And I was thinking that *text* cursor color could be a nice way of current language indication. I'm using three languages, and while typing in Gmail or somewhere, we look at the text cursor. So for convenience reasons it would be a nice way to adapt separate color (or text cursor form) for each language.

I don't know if this is already implemented. Would be nice to use this feature. Would appreciate if you can point me in right direction.

As I said, this is not about mouse cursor/pointer, this is about the cursor in text fields.

Comment: (Commenting until I get more info). [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/284855/421237) might have an option for editing the text cursor colour. Then it would be a matter of connecting this to a dectection in the currently selected IME language.

Comment: Text bar/cursor itself cannot change because it's bound to the color of whatever text box it is part of. Would it be a satisfactory solution if Unity launcher changed according to language ?

Answer (score 1):

Make a shell script that tests weather how your language (`$LANG`) is set. Then, it output a value of a colored prompt accordingly.

In `.bashrc`, you would then set the `promptvars` shell option, and then set the bash prompt to the output of that shell script, like this:

```
PS1="`/full/path/your-script.sh`\$ "
```

That way, your script will be invoked each and every time you get a command prompt and it will generate the corresponding prompt string according to how `LANG` is set.

How do you generate a colored prompt? It will imposible for me to describe it without transcribing a color table... However, the easy way is to go to http://ezprompt.net/ and have it generate it for you on either case, and then just copy the generated colorized prompts on each particular case.

Comment: That's a good idea, but it will be limited to bash only, and only terminal window.  OP wanted cursor set per GUI window, e.g. firefox + english -> cursor red, Libreoffice + german -> green.